# Is there a "show touches" application?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchpad, multi-touch, touchscreen

Is there an application that will "show touches" similar to what is found in Android's developer options?

I have a 10 point multitouch monitor (Planar Helium PCT2785) and it appears to only support single touch on Ubuntu 13.04 out of the box. I would like a "show touches" application as a diagnostic tool.

Thanks

Comment: I'd also like this, but for an Ubuntu Touch phone...